# Delete a file remotely(with specific credentials) using java code

Tags: java, credentials

Helo,

I am designing a program using java that will help me at my work.

Basically we have an app that requires deletion of 2 files (phonebook data). The problem is that there are many offices and they don't all have the same administrative user and password.

That is why i am creating a program that goes directly to the remote path and deletes the file after I give them the correct user and password.

But the problem is how will i pass the administrative acc and password when it connects? For example in windows:
I go to "\192.168.5.20\c$\users\XYZ\appdata\phonebook\numnber.txt"
but this prompts a window in which I enter the local admin and password of the computer.

How do i delete this file in java and configure the user and pass??

Answer (score 0):

- You have to create server and deploy server on remote machine with integrated windows auth system
- Create client app which will ask for credentials and send credentials to server
- Server should validate credentials and delete files

Answer (score 0):

You are choosing wrong programming language, use a unix shell script or windows command file/batch file.

all you need to do is login to each machine with credentials and delete at its path, would be very easy everytime just run the file.